# How to create a new Authority in jHipster?

Tags: jhipster

I wonder if it is possible to create a new Authority in Jhispter. I tried adding a ROLE_WRITER:

/project/src/main/java/location/security/AuthoritiesConstants.java

```
package location.security;

/**
 * Constants for Spring Security authorities.
 */
public final class AuthoritiesConstants {

    public static final String ADMIN = "ROLE_ADMIN";

    public static final String USER = "ROLE_USER";

    public static final String WRITER = "ROLE_WRITER";

    public static final String ANONYMOUS = "ROLE_ANONYMOUS";

    private AuthoritiesConstants() {
    }
}
```

When I run the app, it does not crash, but when I tried to change the localhost:9000/#/user-management ROLE in the profile, it did not offer me the option.

So I went to the database and add a new ROLE in the JHI_AUTHORITY Table and now it appears in the user-management, but I have the feeling that i'm getting into trouble if I mess around with the User Entity.

- Is there any official way of doing it? (that I am not aware of)
- Is there any danger with doing it?
- Is there anything else that I should consider?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any official way of doing it? (that I am not aware of)

Have you seen `src/main/resources/liquibase/authorities.csv`? I think that is a right place to add a new authority before production, and when you are in production stage, then it is recommended to add your change(insert into) as liquibase changeset.

> Is there any danger with doing it?

AFAIK new role will work like other existing roles in Spring security context. having said that I might misunderstood your question.

> Is there anything else that I should consider?

Automation, this type of manual changes will cause dysfunction in  production or new installation, so we need to automate this type of changes for both situations.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sid!!! i didn't see the /rarotest-1a/src/main/resources/config/liquibase/authorities.csv file. If I add it at the CSV will it be automatically added to the database when run the project? By dangers I mean, what can go wrong later on? What type of disfunctions could cause?

Comment: @Mike Note `authorities.csv` triggers from `00000000000000_initial_schema.xml` so every things works fine in a fresh database, but not those that initial schema already applied. About adding new role I didn't notice any issue. Later you may notice for example order matters in security configuration, for example `.antMatchers("/api/onlyWriters/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.WRITER)` need to be above `.antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()` line, etc, which need to be tested by you anyway. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Although this is already answered, I think it's a good idea to put a link to a related tip posted in the official website of JHipster:

https://www.jhipster.tech/tips/025_tip_create_new_authority.html

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, I added drop-first: true parameter to src/main/resources/config/application-dev.yml:

```
....

    liquibase:
            contexts: dev
            drop-first: true

....
```

It seems like it ais a parameter to regenerate the database (for development mode).